# "Site Health" issue after adding new XML sitemap in webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

Recently I replaced the `sitemap.xml` in Google WebmasterTools, but in the dashboard it is showing in the last position **by site health**. I don't know why it is showing in the last position, before it was on the top of all sites.

I need to know, is this normal behavior or has something gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I am not entirely sure I understand your problem. Not your fault of course. With that in mind, I will work with some assumptions that may not be your scenario exactly.

The first thing you need to know is that Google Webmaster Tools lags behind about 2 days normally and may not update any sitemap status for longer than that. It may not update your sitemap status until Google fetches and reads your sitemap file. Keep this in mind.

I think there is an expectation that any sitemap is in the root directory of the website. I cannot recall if this is a specific rule, but this is where I would be putting the sitemap. As well, I create a sitemap with a specific name and not just sitemap.xml. The reason why I do this is to control who can read it. This is an option. I am not recommending it as a solution. From there, I submit the sitemap to Google, Bing, and so forth. I would be checking again to make sure that your sitemap name is correct. Once you submit a sitemap, you do not have to do it again unless you create a sitemap of a different name. Google, Bing, and the like will keep checking your sitemap files from time to time without your having to resubmitting it. Google will indicate that it has revisited your site map in WMT when it does.